# How can I tell when I need to trim my goat's hooves and how do I tell if I've trimmed them short enough?

Tags: health, grooming, goats

How can I tell when I need to trim my goat's hooves? I trim them regularly but am not sure if I do it often enough or if I'm being over-zealous. Or maybe when I'm trimming them I don't trim them short enough so I have to do it too often?

Also, when do you start trimming a kid's hooves? Is it a certain age or does it depend on the length of the hooves? So far I've been doing it just a very little at a young age with the idea of getting them used to it young.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the age of the kids but on my grandpa's farm we will trim the hooves once they get long.Trim the sides and any hoof that has curved under the goat, if you see red stop cutting.I'm not a professional but this is what we do.

Comment: I like this answer. Are you able to provide a little more detail on what is considered long? Pics would be even better :)